# Passing array to controller using jquery Post

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

```
var sc = new Array();
var i =0;
el.find(".colorable").each(function () {
    sc[i++] = $(this).attr("src");
});
$.post("/Edit/ChangeImageColor", { src : sc , s: source, t: target }, function () {
    alert("done");
});
```

I am trying to pass array `( sc )` to server but it shows null in src

```
    public JsonResult ChangeImageColor(string[] src, string s, string t)
    {
```

Can anybody tell me what i am missing?

Comment: what language is the server, and in what format are you sending the parameters?

Comment: You'd have to know how the server expects such an array of values. jQuery encodes an array by default as `src[]=1&src[]=2` (note the `[]`). Maybe you need `src=1&src=2`... you should check that, have a look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Comment: you should use http://www.json.org/

Comment: and are you _sure_ that `sc` is actually filled before it's sent?

Comment: server language is c# and sending in default format (string)

Comment: you mean urlencoded?  and is `el` just an element, or a jQuery object?  It needs to be the latter.

Comment: i just want to know how we send an array to server that`s it

Comment: @gaurav felixkling already told you how jQuery does it my default.

Comment: Your problem is not sending the array but receiving the array. There's a mismatch between how you send it and how the server expects to receive it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ASP.NET MVC 3 you could send it as JSON request:

```
var sc = new Array();
var i = 0;
el.find(".colorable").each(function () {
    sc[i++] = $(this).attr("src");
});
$.ajax({
    url: '/Edit/ChangeImageColor',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: JSON.stringify({ src: sc, s: source, t: target }),
    success: function() {
        alert("done");
    }
});
```

If you are using an older version of ASP.NET MVC you may take a look at the [following blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx) which illustrates how you could integrate a custom json provider factory allowing you to send JSON requests to controller actions.

Comment: perfect answer thanks and i am using MVC 3

Comment: I have updated your question to put the proper tag: `asp.net-mvc-3`.

Comment: thanks and i will remmember this while asking another questions in future

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding your (probably server side) parameter passing fault, I thought you might find this useful:

```
var sc = el.find(".colorable").map(function() {
    return this.src;
}).get();
```

which is a much simpler way of collecting the properties of a set of elements in an array.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your action method as follows

```
 public JsonResult ChangeImageColor(IEnumerable<string> src, string s, string t)
{
```